# Transform a variable of a dataframe with the variable name stored in another variable

Tags: r

I would like to transform a variable of a dataframe.
The name of the variable is store in another variable.
I could do it with dplyr as following.
I was wondering if there was a R base solution.

```
library(dplyr)
 
data=data.frame(Var1=c(8,4,32,41,NA, 8, 4,2,1,10), Var2=c(9,NA,4,8,NA,8,8, NA, 6,21), Jah=c(9,7,56,43,9,NA,NA,NA, 74,7))

> data
   Var1 Var2 Jah
1     8    9   9
2     4   NA   7
3    32    4  56
4    41    8  43
5    NA   NA   9
6     8    8  NA
7     4    8  NA
8     2   NA  NA
9     1    6  74
10   10   21   7

variable_to_analyse = "Var1"


data %>% 
  mutate(!!variable_to_analyse := ifelse( is.na(.data[[variable_to_analyse]]), 0, .data[[variable_to_analyse]]))

   Var1 Var2 Jah
1     8    9   9
2     4   NA   7
3    32    4  56
4    41    8  43
5     0   NA   9
6     8    8  NA
7     4    8  NA
8     2   NA  NA
9     1    6  74
10   10   21   7

data$Var1[is.na(data$Var1)]=0
```

Is there a way to use the second solution using variable_to_analyse ?

Comment: If you need base R in place replacement: `data[is.na(data[,variable_to_analyse]), variable_to_analyse] <- 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data[is.na(data[,variable_to_analyse]), variable_to_analyse] <- 0
data
   Var1 Var2 Jah
1     8    9   9
2     4   NA   7
3    32    4  56
4    41    8  43
5     0   NA   9
6     8    8  NA
7     4    8  NA
8     2   NA  NA
9     1    6  74
10   10   21   7
```

---

If you have to replace several columns use:

```
data[variables_to_analyse][is.na(data[variables_to_analyse])] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very interesting as it allows to transform several variable in one code line if I store their name in variable_to_analyse.

Comment: @Av65 if you have several variables then do selection first before replacement!!. Check the edit